# Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на следующий объект, фокус прошлого нажатого объекта не терялся?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть список из кнопок, пронумерованных от 1 до 20. Мне нужно, чтобы после клика на одну кнопку, а затем на вторую, фокус первой кнопки не исчезал автоматически. Также, нужно чтобы фокус с кнопки исчезал только при клике на ее саму, ни в коем другом случае. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту задачку. Второй день над ней сижу, ничего не получаеться. Вот HTML-код для удобства:

```
<ul class="genre-list">
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn1">Comedy</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn2">Criminal</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn3">Detective</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn4">Thriller</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn5">Romance</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn6">War</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn7">Historical</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn8">Supernatural</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn9">Drama</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn10">Western</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn11">Adventure</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn12">Political</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn13">Sci-Fi</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn14">Musical</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn15">Fantasy</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn16">Biography</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="genre-col">
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn17">Horror</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn18">Action</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn19">Disaster</button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="genre-item">
                        <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn20">Sports</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>
```

CSS-код:

```
.genre-list {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
padding-top: 120px;
}


.genre-item {
margin: 60px 70px;
transition: all 0.8s;}
}

.genre-item-btn {
width: 120px;
height: 40px;
font-size: 23px;
color: #fff;
background-color: #202020;
border: none;
outline: none;
border-radius: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
cursor: pointer;
user-select: none;
transition: all 0.4s;
}

.genre-item-btn:focus {
outline: 5px solid #ff8a00;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это вам не focus надо, а какой-то переключатель. Такой сойдет?

```js
document.querySelector('.genre-list').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.genre-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.genre-item {
  margin: 60px 70px;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.genre-item-btn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202020;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Marvel', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

.genre-item-btn.active {
  outline: 5px solid #ff8a00;
}
```

```html
<ul class="genre-list">
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn1">Comedy</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn2">Criminal</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn3">Detective</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn4">Thriller</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn5">Romance</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn6">War</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn7">Historical</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn8">Supernatural</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn9">Drama</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn10">Western</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn11">Adventure</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn12">Political</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn13">Sci-Fi</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn14">Musical</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn15">Fantasy</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn16">Biography</button>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="genre-col">
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn17">Horror</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn18">Action</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn19">Disaster</button>
    </li>
    <li class="genre-item">
      <button type="button" class="genre-item-btn" id="genreBtn20">Sports</button>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам! Да, это то, что мне нужно было.